# Typescript function return type relay

Tags: typescript

I have a simple class that implements the visitor pattern:

```js
abstract class MyNode {};
class MyNodeA extends MyNode {};
class MyNodeB extends MyNode {};

abstract class NodeVisitor {
  abstract visitMyNodeA(node: MyNodeA): unknown;
  abstract visitMyNodeB(node: MyNodeB): unknown;

  public visit(node: MyNode) {
    if(node instanceof MyNodeA) {
      return this.visitMyNodeA(node);
    } else if(node instanceof MyNodeB) {
      return this.visitMyNodeB(node);
    } else {
      throw new Error('Unknown node type on visitor');
    }
  } 
}
```

and later, I want to have custom return types on each visit function when I implement `NodeVisitor`

```js
class MyNodeVisitor extends NodeVisitor {
  visitMyNodeA(node: MyNodeA): number {
    return 1;
  }
  visitMyNodeB(node: MyNodeB): number {
    return this.visit(new MyNodeA()) + 1;
  }
}
```

but this generates an error because the TypeScript compiler does not realize that a call on `visit` with a parameter of type `MyNodeA` redirects to the `visitMyNodeA` function which now returns a `number`.

How would I go about implementing such a solution?

Comment: "this generates an error"... what error, specifically?  Could you make this into a [mcve] and possibly even link to an online IDE like the Playground that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @jcalz I am sorry, you are right. The example I had before did not generate an error as I was typecasting to String. Updated the example to clearly show my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, the compiler can't figure that out by itself.  You can help it do so, at the expense of more complexity (and less type safety inside the `visit()` implementation).  My suggestion is to give `visit()` a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) signature whose return type is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) based on the [polymorphic `this` type of subclasses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types):

```
abstract class MyNode {myNode = "myNode"}
class MyNodeA extends MyNode {a = "a"}
class MyNodeB extends MyNode {b = "b"}

abstract class NodeVisitor {
  abstract visitMyNodeA(node: MyNodeA): unknown;
  abstract visitMyNodeB(node: MyNodeB): unknown;

  // call signature    
  public visit<T extends MyNode>(
    node: T
  ): T extends MyNodeA ? ReturnType<this["visitMyNodeA"]> : 
     T extends MyNodeB ? ReturnType<this["visitMyNodeB"]> : 
    never;

  // implementation signature is wider
  public visit(node: MyNode): unknown {
    if (node instanceof MyNodeA) {
      return this.visitMyNodeA(node);
    } else if (node instanceof MyNodeB) {
      return this.visitMyNodeB(node);
    } else {
      throw new Error("Unknown node type on visitor");
    }
  }
}    
class MyNodeVisitor extends NodeVisitor {
  visitMyNodeA(node: MyNodeA): number {
    return 1;
  }
  visitMyNodeB(node: MyNodeB): number {
    return this.visit(new MyNodeA()) + 1;
  }
}
```

Does that work?  The idea is that you are leading the compiler through the analysis that if you pass in a `MyNodeA` that `visit()` will return the result of `this.visitMyNodeA(node)`, and the same for `MyNodeB`.

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgsgTwHIHsATAUwQG8BbPI0gXgQCIqCSGBfAKBTQxxeICCCYgA8IxAHaFe1EuWAJ6DYOy6p0WWcQBCwsZOmb+5EIsYhVHUJBjwk6jPwBqASzAuI+KOQ4IE16DhEADc3Dz4aAQAKCRoALiNIgEoEgFcJAGtYgHcJAG5ff3BAu1D3CAiSbRj4xKqUhHSs-FyCwoAHVJBkF1gEMo8AHgAVPXEpGX4APijCv1iSBOHChtHRccNKwQQAfgQAJWIIVKgJYex24kGIAAs3AG0GAYqtAQYAXSmEBLm-Nf0JnUdLsDkcTmcLldbg8nmEXvxtB8vj8-PNiMFiFACn5Ot1ev04TVFkCGk0chIfKiEC4AGYIImkFwSSDACSwYj4OlbARJSlUhBQMGnBDQsAAOme3IZSWxqLYwmQYEZdIZ1OZEFZ7M5QO0vLIvz8guOwtFErhW2qC2IMt+8uIitI+v5IpuUBaCAkxGyCAAolA3VAogwAKqZckemgiyEIfAU55eBg2qmcPycThqHhA1zlLxjAyOGjZjy5p0E8pSq0JbkNCSpCggTF8w1CikARllKbL4S0ltqFprdYb3lLzeNFNNzxiXqB0SSvIA1Ah24U0xwgA)

Comment: Might I suggest `public visit<T extends MyNode>(node: T): ReturnType<Extract<this[Exclude<keyof this, 'visit'>], (node: T) => any>>;` ? IT should extract the return type based on the passed in parameter as long as the visit* methods are public. Might get a bit brittle if you add extra methods that satisfy the signature `(node: MyNode) => any` but it might be an option :)

Comment: @jcalz Seems like this solution works, but only when the visit* methods are public, any workaround for when they are not?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I like it; I agree about possible brittleness but there are probably workarounds.
@Komninos if the methods are not public you will have a very hard time referring to them programmatically (since they are no longer part of `Pick<NodeVisitor, keyof NodeVisitor>`).  Not sure if anyone else has a suggestion for that, but do note this seems to be different from the question as asked.